# Runtime Error Cannot find module "../signup/signup"

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been working on a project in Ionic and after running the file I got the the runtime error saying Cannot find module "../signup/signup". I then went into the project and checked to see if it the file and directory existed which it didn't. I then proceeded to create a directory and file to see if that would fix the problem and it did not.  Here is the code for signup.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component(
{
  templateUrl: 'signup.html'
})

export class SignupPage
{
  static get parameters()
  {
    return [[NavController]];
  }
  constructor(public nav)
  {
    this.nav = nav;
  }
}
```

Here is the page that I have made the import

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

import {NavController, AlertController} from 'ionic-angular';

import {SignupPage} from '../signup/signup';
import {TabsPage} from "../tabs/tabs";

import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, AbstractControl, Validators, NgControl} from '@angular/forms';

import {AuthService} from '../../providers/auth-service';


@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
    loginForm: FormGroup;
    submitAttempt: boolean = false;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public fb: FormBuilder, private _auth: AuthService, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
        email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9]+(\\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[a-z]{2,15})$')])],
        password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(16)])]
    });
}
}
```

Here are the files as it is setup in the directory

[project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa6a3.png)

These are the errors I seem to be getting whenever I run ionic serve. This may also be adding to the cause of the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOeVh.png)

I have looked around and the solutions I have tried don't seem to work. I also seem to be getting an error on line 8 of my login file where it attempts to import '@angular/forms' which may be the cause of the problem. Help is gladly appreciated

Comment: Do you have your signup page added to src/app/app.module.ts, both in the declarations and entryComponents section?

Comment: If your login page and your sign up page are in the same exact directory, use this: import {SignupPage} from './signup';